# Does Heroku free-tier limit SEO capabilities?

Tags: heroku

I'm hosting a small project via Heroku, using free dyno hours. The site was appearing on Google, but would vanish after awhile. This kept happening, until the site is just no longer on Google. I was wondering if my sites idling time was affecting the Google search appearance.

I've looked to see if this was something known, but couldn't find anything. So, does using Heroku free-tier affect the results on Google from idling?

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: I'd assume so. If google crawls your site and has a 15 second load time, this will hurt your score.

Comment: That's what I thought, but wasn't entirely sure. The site itself is pretty darn fast, scoring a 97 from Google's own site speed test. I'll probably upgrade to a paid dyno.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly or on purpose. Your app will run exactly the same whether it's on the free plan, or on a paid one.
As long as you run "Hobby" or "Standard" dynos (and not "Private" or "Performance" ones), you may actually end up on the same instance as someone with a free dyno.

However, and as mentioned by tkausl in the comments, Google will negatively consider your website if it has long loading times. Free apps will idle, which triggers a longer loading time (or even downtime, if you've reached your monthly free quota).